# I don't understand how these recursive calls could finish

Tags: python, recursion, boolean

Here is my simple Python function:

```py
def f(b):
    return b and f(b)
```

To me this must be an infinite loop, no matter the value of `b`, because `b` is always the same. But:

- With `f(True)` I get an overflow, which is what I expected
- When I run `f(False)` I get `False`!

I'm very curious about that.

Comment: `and` performs short-circuit evaluation. As the first operand is false, the second is not evaluated as it is already clear that the `and` should evaluate to false anyway.

Comment: `b and f(b)` does not call `f(b)` if b is false.

Answer (score 2):

Recursion stops when `b` is falsey, i.e. `False` (or an empty string, or zero).

In some more detail,

```
x and y
```

does not evaluate `y` if `x` is `False` (or, as explicated above, another value which is interpreted as that when converted into a `bool` value, which Python calls "falsey"), as it is then impossible for `y` to affect the outcome of the expression. This is often called "short-circuiting".